# Declaring an iVar, property

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have just inherited an iOS project and just have a query about the way the ivars and properties are assigned.

In this project ivars are named similar to the property but begin with an underscore. Then, when the property is being synthesized it is done like this

```
@synthesize property = _ivar;
```

I find this a little odd. I have just worked on one iOS project before but when I was doing both the ivar and property had the same name. I would then simply synthesize the property and everything was hunky dory.

Why did this guy do things differently? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere along the line it became conventional to use the `_var` form as protection against accidentally referencing the variable when the developer should have been referencing `self.property`.  It is now established to the point that, with the latest tools, you can drop the `@synthesize` lines entirely and `@synthesize x = _x;` is simulated automatically.

Comment: Ok, well now i'm confused. The guy is following that convention fair enough. But, in all his code he reference _ivar and not self.property? Is this incorrect?

Comment: The main place where people need to use `_ivar` is when they write a custom "getter".  In that case, you can't write `self.property` because it would be a recursive call to the same "getter" method.  Most uses outside of that, I'd consider suspicious until I saw exactly the context.

Comment: Well that depends, if you use the `_var` then KVO will not be triggered and maybe this is something that the previous developer wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You not missing anything, it a choice of style. When using the `_ivar` way you can't easily make a mistake with the ivar or the property. Also as stated by [Mike Weller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49658/mike-weller) this is what Apple recommends.

If also help if you are using delegate where they pass the send with the same name as your ivar. For example:

If you declare a property `tableView` and do the same for the ivar then the compiler will complain about redeclaring the variable `tableView` in a method like:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // Dot some thing with the table object
}
```

Because both the class scope and the method scope hava the variable name `tableView` and you can't really tell which one is to be used.

In the latest versions of Xcode you do not even have to declare the ivar's any more, if you header file looks like this:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> 
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

Then you don't even have to `@synthesize` the property any more, this is done for you automatically and a ivar with the name  `_tableView` is also create. But accessing the variable via the property with the `self.tableView` syntax is preferred.

There is an exception on this, if you where to reintroduce a property with which already exists in the super calls you must call `@synthesize`. It will again create the '_ivar' for you.

<strike>An other exception is that if you are using primitive types the compiler will not create the`_ivar` for you. You don't need to create them both in the header you can just do  `@synthesize myInt = _myInt` and the ivar is created for you.</strike>

Comment: Note that Apple now recommends you use the underscore prefix (see the WWDC 2012 videos)

Comment: Interesting, I used to to the inverse. all params begin with underscore. :-/

Comment: @conor that goes against the normal Apple guide lines, but you are free to use what every you like.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean about primitive types?  (If I declare `@property (assign) int myInt;`, I can reference `_myInt` with no other declarations/definitions.)

Comment: Sorry the latest version of Xcode seem to be doing this correctly now. Yes, if you declare `@property (assign) int myInt;` you can reference `_myInt` with out declaring `@synthesize myInt` or `@synthesize myInt = _myInt`

Answer (score 0):

this practice forces you to  call and set your iVars using property. Incase where you want to use iVar,u call it by _iVar, otherwise there will be no chance of calling iVar directly without using property by mistake. It will show error and you will get reminded that oh i need to put self.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of XCode you need not to synthesize, it does for you. But again with an underscore.

However you can override it by declaring it `@synthesize property=property;` or `@synthesize property;` and even you will be aware that you can give any other name `@synthesize property=myproperty;`

However initially it was just a matter of style, like using variable name and action names e.g. numberArray, nameTextField, cancelButton, but now it is seldom used and people are asked to name numbers, name, cancel respectively.

But I would suggest to follow apple guidelines to use _property.